# TypeScript: Assert a Type for the Rest of the Function

Tags: typescript

The way I’ve set up types, a `Store` differs from a `PersistedStore` only in the presence of an ID, which a store gets once it’s been persisted (sent to the server).

Consider this snippet, in which the server has just responded with an ID for the newly created store. In all that follows, I need to explicitly assert that the store is now a `PersistedStore` whenever I touch it.

```js
const id = (response as {id: number}).id;
(store as PersistedStore).id = id;
this.cache.set(id, store as PersistedStore);
return store as PersistedStore;
```

Does TypeScript provide a way to assert a certain type for the rest of the function?

I am aware of [type predicates](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicateshttp://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates), and I’ve found a way to abuse them to write my own type assertion, but I’m unhappy with how the code would look if I used it:

```js
assertType<T>(_: any): _ is T {
  return true;
}
```

```js
const id = (response as {id: number}).id;
if (assertType<Persistedstore>(store)) {
  store.id = id;
  this.cache.set(id, store);
  return store;
}
```

In the spirit of producing code that advertises its intent, I feel bad about writing what is essentially an `if(true)` statement. From looking at the code one might wonder if it is possible that the store is not actually persisted by now.

Comment: `assertType<T>(_: any): asserts _ is T {}` then `if` is not needed

Comment: Declare a new variable of type `PersistedStore` and put `store as PersistedStore` into it then use it instead of `store` in the rest of the function.

Comment: @AlekseyL. While the answer to that question suggests that language construct, it was not at all clear to me how it would translate to my case. I believe your second comment qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @bleistift2 I've updated linked answer to include type assertion example